# How to add prettier command before code commit or on save file through devdependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-formatting, prettier

I am working with react project.

I want my vscode to autoformat when I save the code but want to do by adding some package inside package.json(I am not sure whether it is possible or not) & not with vscode because people have their own configuration in vscode so to be identical with those config i want to do it with some prettier. Here is my prettier config file

.prettierrc.json

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "printWidth": 120
}
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.20.0",
    "browser-image-compression": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^12.0.5",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.14.4",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
    "react-multiselect-checkboxes": "^0.1.1",
    "react-number-format": "^4.9.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.8",
    "redux-observable": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "npx prettier --write .",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) for hooking into `git commit` (and many more commands) and execute your own `npm` script?

Comment: yes but did not get "prettified" code on commit.

Comment: Could you add the "prettified" script to the description? and also the relevant husky hook?

Comment: @AnindyaDey Pls check the updated question

Comment: what about using [Run on save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave). Add a prettier script to your package.json and  run that script everytime you/other save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prettier with a pre-commit tool. This can re-format your files that are marked as “staged” via git add before you commit.

Make sure Prettier is installed and is in your devDependencies before you proceed.

> npx mrm@2 lint-staged

use this link for further info

[Pre-commit Hook](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html)